# Avatar image transparency?

Tags: support

I have tried to upload a variety of images with transparency in `gif` and `png` format. I have saved them in 32x32 size and larger, but every time I upload them the transparency is black. I even copied an existing one that works from another user, removed his image, saved it and still no luck.

I've tried both GIMP and Adobe Photoshop.

Any advice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We use Gravatar [who supposedly support transparency (as of 2008)](http://blog.gravatar.com/2008/06/06/image-transparency-you-want-it-you-got-it/) so this is either:

- A pure GIMP problem,
- A GIMP+Gravatar problem, or
- A Gravatar issue.

I suspect your GIMP export settings are the most likely problem. You're either doing something wrong or you've knocked one of the wrong things. Can you upload the image as part of your post? (edit it, add an image and upload it to imgur)

If you're sure there's nothing squiffy there, I would suggest another application or [an online image processor](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=resize+transparent+gif+online) to double-check the GIFfiness of the input before blaming Gravatar. If this works, you've found a bizarre quirk between what GIMP produces and what Gravatar accepts. You should report this as a bug to Gravatar and maybe also GIMP.

If you've tried another application and you've managed to process it online with other tools and it still doesn't work in Gravatar, then it's time to [talk to Gravatar](https://en.gravatar.com/support/).

Comment: Gravatar was answer, same image, uploaded, no issue, so stackexchange must mess with the transparency some how.

Comment: @Doogfar They're loaded directly from Gravatar (the email is MD5 hashed and it just appended to their standard URL with dimensions) so StackExchange *can't* be interfering.

Comment: Possibly a bug then..

Comment: My Gravatar is partially transparent, so it definitely *works*. And for me Doogfar's Gravatar shows as transparent now as well.